# Is there alternative for google places autocomplete in leaflet with angular6?

Tags: angular6, ngx-leaflet

I am working in an angular6 project. I need to integrate location in reactive form. Google map requires payment, so my client asked me to find an open source one. I ended up with [ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet).But I couldn't find any google places autocomplete alternative in leaflet for angular.

I am beginner in angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with ngx-google-places-autocomplete

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-google-places-autocomplete

Comment: Google now require payment.Is this is payment free?

Comment: Nope, you will require API key .
You can refer this for free key for development mode.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Client need free API (: